# Can't access Claims in User.Identity but can see them in break-point view

Tags: c#, intellisense, identity, claims-based-identity

I know that the field *Claims* is in *User.Identity* because I can see it and its contents using break-point view, as the image depicts. However, when I try to access it with intellisense during development, I can't. The same goes for Immediate Window - the property seems not to be there.

What's up with that?

[image]

Comment: In your case, if you do `var something = User.Identity` what will be the type of `something` variable? Most likely, your instance type has the property, and you variable/property type does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

User.Identity property is most likely of [`IIdentity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity(v=vs.110).aspx) type. On the other hand the instance stored in it, is of [ClaimsIdentity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsidentity(v=vs.110).aspx) type as you can see in the debugger.

You need to [cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) one type to the other to access the value:

```
ClaimsIdentity identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;
```

Comment: Oh, you lifted a blanket with that. Suddenly, when I started to poke around with **that** class, instead of the interface, I found out a bunch of answers to other WTFs I've had the last week. Security isn't my strong suit and I'm trying to change that state. It's not going well. Yet. Up to now I've had this feeling of magical stuff happening without me understanding where, why and how. **But now**, I'm getting Amazing Grace - "*...was blind and now I see...*". +1

Answer (score 0):

You can also right click on the Claims in your debugger popup and click "Copy Expression".

You can then paste in the immediate window to seen how to access it.  In my case it was this

```
((Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)((Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal)User).Identity).Claims
```

pretty nasty huh..